# Suspension reason shows on main, but not on meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, per-site-meta, account-suspension

I recently discovered that there was a high-rep user suspended on Arqade, so that they could calm down a bit. When I was looking at their profile, I noticed that the suspension reason was shown on their main profile, but not on their meta profile.

Main:
[image: This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on Jul 9 at 23:22.]

Meta: 
[image: This account is temporarily suspended. The suspension period ends on Jul 9 at 23:22.]

Comment: I assume this is a network-wide issue, not a site specific issue. BTW, if anyone needs a link to the profile, just leave a message below.

Comment: There's no need in providing the link, the behavior is similar for any suspended users on any site. Strange it hasn't been reported still, I thought I did it...

Comment: I suspect the main and meta sites doesn't use same databases, but they use completely different ones, with a lot of mirroring. I think it is because the meta users don't exist after registration, but they are automatically created on the first visit (i.e. there is no "meta user" link on the user page of newly created accounts, even in the case if they start with the +100 bonus). And, if my theory is okay, then the probable reason, that these mirroring scripts(?) aren't perfect and don't copy all tables/records, only the more important ones.

Comment: But hopefully somebody having actual knowledge from the site internals and not only theories as me :-), will explain it. SE is surprisingly open in its internals. Until that, here is an experiment: could you find somebody who is caged on the _meta_ site, how looks his normal account? Does this "feature" happen also in the other direction?

Comment: The real question is why these aren't customized per site.  "This account is temporarily suspended for wallhacking."

Comment: @Won't: That customization is reserved specifically for *your* SE account.

Comment: @peterh it is not possible for moderators to contact users privately on Meta sites. It is therefore also not possible to issue a Meta-only suspension.

Comment: @won "This account is temporarily suspended for being a unicorn.", "This account is temporarily suspended for talking with a full mouth.", "This account is temporarily perma-suspended for minor high-severity violations not amounting to gross malfeasance but amounting to high infractions and petty felonies."

Comment: Also reported on MSO in May 2018: [Suspension not shown properly on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367509/1478931) – Shog9 tagged that post as [status-bydesign] at the time. Glorfindel also posted an answer pointing out that mods can't even suspend users directly from the site's meta – only from their profile on the main site (which then extends the suspension to the corresponding meta site) – so I'm guessing this behavior is a result of that.

Comment: As such, I've tagged this post as [status-bydesign] as well, since it's apparently not a bug. (That doesn't preclude someone asking that this behavior be changed, though I have no idea whether that's possible or desirable.)