# Different text for network-wide suspended users on meta

Tags: bug, profile-page, per-site-meta, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

If you look at a profile of a user who is [suspended networkwide](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suspended+network-wide.%22+site:stackexchange.com), you get the text: "This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on..."

However, if you click on "Meta user" and look at the profile of the same user on the corresponding meta, you see just: "This account is temporarily suspended. The suspension period ends on..." (The part that the suspension is *network-wide* is omitted.)

This is probably a minor thing but still - I suppose it is not supposed to work this way. (Maybe sometimes it might lead to confusion. For example, if I remember see that some user was suspended network-wide and then I notice on meta the text which is used for per-site suspensions - it's quite natural that I might be wondering what is going on and whether the network-wide suspension has been revoked.)

Comment: Internally, a network-wide suspension is actually a series of site-wide suspensions with "network-wide" in the spot for the reason. Thus, this is essentially the same bug as [Suspension reason shows on main, but not on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280130/suspension-reason-shows-on-main-but-not-on-meta).